# End a loop if the user select a specific function

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers, do-while

Hi I need little help with a problem!

I have a main class which contains a loop. 
Inside this loop the user can call different functions that do different things but I want that if the user select a certain function it displays a message and the loop ends.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rest_at_inn();
void train();
void battle_demon_lord();
void Quit_Game();

int main() {

    //Declare variable and pointer
    float days_remaining = 8;
    int current_hp = 10;
    int hp_remaining = 10;
    int MAX = 10;
    int experience = 0;
    int selection;

    //Loops a menu that asks the user to make a selectio and repet it until either days or HP are less or equal to zero
    do {
        printf("Days remaining: %f, HP: %d, EXP: %d\n\n", days_remaining, hp_remaining, experience);
        printf("1 - Rest at Inn\n");
        printf("2 - Train\n");
        printf("3 - Fight the Demon Lord\n");
        printf("4 - Quit Game\n\n");
        printf("Select: \n");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        printf("\n");

        //Execute the selection
        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                rest_at_inn(&days_remaining, &hp_remaining, &MAX);
                break;
            case 2:
                train(&days_remaining, &hp_remaining, &experience);
                break;
            case 3:
                battle_demon_lord(&current_hp);
                break;
            case 4:
                Quit_Game();
                break;
        }

    } while (days_remaining > 0 && current_hp > 0);

    return 0;

}

//This function reduces the days by 1 and resets the HP to 10

void rest_at_inn(float *days_remaining, int *hp_remaining, int *MAX) {

    *hp_remaining = 10;
    *days_remaining -= 1;
    if (*days_remaining > 0)
        printf("You rested up the at the inn\n\n");
    else /*(*days_remaining<=0)*/
        printf("Game Over");

}

//This function reduces the days by 0.5 and the HP by 2 and adds 10 to the experience

void train(float *days_remaining, int *hp_remaining, int *experience) {

    *experience += 10;
    *hp_remaining = *hp_remaining - 2;
    *days_remaining = *days_remaining - 0.5;
    printf("You did some training!\n\n");

}

//This function sets the HP to 0 and prints a string

void battle_demon_lord(int *current_hp) {

    *current_hp = 0;
    printf("He's too strong!\n\n");
    printf("Game Over!");
}

// This function prints a string

void Quit_Game() {

    printf("Good bye!\n\n");

}
```

I think it should be a parameter in the do_while but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: By the way, Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an exit condition for when the user selects 4.

You can do this:

```
} while (days_remaining>0 && current_hp>0 && selection != 4);
```

Or this:

```
case 4 :
    Quit_Game();
    return 0;
```

Or this:

```
void Quit_Game()  {

    printf ("Good bye!\n\n");
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Note that the third method requires `stdlib.h` to be included for the `exit` funtion.

Answer (score 2):

If the `switch` is the last statement of your loop, add a `mustQuit` flag variable before the `do` of your `do` / `while` loop, and set it to zero. When end-user chooses the quit option, set `mustQuit` to `1`. Add the `!mustQuit` condition to your loop.

```
int mustQuit = 0;
do {
    ... // some statements here
    switch (selection) {
    ...
    case 4 :
        mustQuit = 1;
        Quit_Game();
        break;
    }
} while (!mustQuit && days_remaining > 0 && current_hp > 0);
```

If you have more statements after `switch`, an alternative with a conditional `break` in the middle may be more optimal:

```
do {
    int mustQuit = 0;
    ... // some statements here
    switch (selection) {
    ...
    case 4 :
        mustQuit = 1;
        Quit_Game();
        break; // this breaks the switch
    }
    if (mustQuit) {
        break; // this breaks the loop
    }
    ... // More statements here
} while (days_remaining > 0 && current_hp > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want to escape the loop in `case 4`:

Try to use `goto`

```
    case 4 :
        Quit_Game();
        goto out;
        break;
    }

} while (days_remaining>0 && current_hp>0);
out:
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you all! All of you gave great answers!

Comment: `break;`  will never be executed and hence should be removed. And using `goto`s are considered as bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** If you want to just get out of the do-while loop you can add a boolean variable so when it enter the last option it'll be false, like so:

```
bool quit = false;
```

(...)

```
case 4 :
    quit = true;
    printf("Good bye!\n\n");
    break;
```

and add the value at the condition of the do-while:

```
while (days_remaining>0 && current_hp>0 && !quit);
```

So, it'll get out of the do-while loop and continue the code.

**(2)** If you want to finish the program, add a return 0 and forget about the boolean value, like this:

```
case 4 :
    printf("Good bye!\n\n");
    return 0;
```

**REMEMBER: If you are doing it on a C based code, it wont support the reserved words like, `true` and `false`. You must use 0 for false and other number for true, preferably 1.**

Comment: Note that `bool quit = false;` requires `stdbool.h` which is available in C99 and above. "_it wont support the reserved words like, `true` and `false`._" -- "_reserved_"? Also, they *are* defined in `stdbool.h`. "_`return 0;
    break;`_" -- `break;` will never be executed and hence should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm aware of the break situation, I left unintentionally. And thank you for the tip on the C99 library, didn't know that true and false was able with those.